# Почему такой корень?

Tags: морфемика

Почему в слове "название" корень "зв", а не "назв".

Comment: Такой корень  в словаре Тихонова. Если у вас есть причины сомневаться в этом, то укажите это в вопросе.

Comment: Как я думаю,  "звать" в смысле называть в современном языке не используется уже.

Comment: Вы можете уточнить это в толковых словарях. https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=звать&mode=slovari  Звать и называть  - это синонимы по словарю. Пункт 2.1 и 2.2.

Comment: Убедили вы меня.